# How do I "unbake" an armature/character and add new actions

Tags: animation, armature, keyframes

I have a simple humanoid character with a walk cycle that i created and then animated it along a path using cyclic repeat. I have already baked the animation because I was using wiggle bones and wanted to test to see how well it was working. I now want to revert back to the NLA editor and work with the original action strip and add some new actions including jumping and climbing, unfortunately I'm at a loss after searching for an hour on how to possibly un-bake the keyframes and work on a new sequence with the correct actions. Hoping that I won't have to start over and re-append the character and walk cycle because I added 2 bones that are working well on this model/want to know how to avoid this in the future as well if possible. I hope I've been clear about what I'm trying to do but essentially I have a simple repeating walk cycle already baked in but I want to go back to the NLA stage and somehow unbake my current keyframes. Thank you to anyone who reads this or has helpful advice!

Answer (score 0):

After messing around a little more, I found my original action strip is still intact and I'm assuming now it's a matter of deleting keyframes (unbaking) and then starting over once I create the new actions I want to mix in. For some reason before I posted this I was unable to see the Walk_Cycle action I had created before and I'm not sure what fixed it but I am currently in pose mode with the armature selected and the NLA editor open and it just showed up. Now I feel confident that I can delete my keyframes and I won't be left with a lifeless T-pose. Leaving this here in the hopes it helps someone else.